# Azure AI Document Analyzer does not accept images from azure blob storage but others

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage, azure-form-recognizer

I want to analyze pictures to extract texts from them. I have a Spring Boot application that uses `com.azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis`

I have a blob storage where i published a test jpg what can be accessed from everyone (just double checked in inkognito tab). If i want to anylyze this with this call:

```
SyncPoller<OperationResult, AnalyzeResult> analyzeLayoutResultPoller = documentAnalyzerProvider.getClient().beginAnalyzeDocumentFromUrl(MODEL_ID, <public jpg url from blob storage>);
```

For the image in blob the service returns:

```
com.azure.core.exception.HttpResponseException: Status code 400, "{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Invalid request.","innererror":{"code":"InvalidContent","message":"The file is corrupted or format is unsupported. Refer to documentation for the list of supported formats."}}}"
```

But if i use the original url of image (where i downloaded it) the service works. So for some reason the urls (i previously tried with my own images) from blob storage aren't accepted by document analyzer while they perfectly work if just put in web browser.

If i download the image and analyze the image by uploading to analyzer it is also working.

How to analyze images stored in blob storage in Azure Document Analyzer by URL.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

The problem occurs to be with the URL you are using to obtain the picture from the blob storage. The error message suggests the file is corrupted or that the format is unsupported.

I have a jpeg file with the name **`goodone.jpg`** name in my storage account account.

[image]

My container is private so, I need to fetch the URL with the sas token here is how I'm getting the blob URL from the portal.

**Portal:**

[image]

Now you can use the below Java code to analyse the image using the **`com.azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis`** package.

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.models.*;
import com.azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.DocumentAnalysisClient;
import com.azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.DocumentAnalysisClientBuilder;
import com.azure.core.credential.AzureKeyCredential;
import com.azure.core.util.polling.SyncPoller;


public class App {

  private static final String endpoint = "<Your-endpoint>";
  private static final String key = "<Your-key>";

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    DocumentAnalysisClient client = new DocumentAnalysisClientBuilder()
      .credential(new AzureKeyCredential(key))
      .endpoint(endpoint)
      .buildClient();

    String documentUrl = "<Your blob sas url>";
    String modelId = "prebuilt-document";
    SyncPoller < OperationResult, AnalyzeResult > analyzeDocumentPoller =
      client.beginAnalyzeDocumentFromUrl(modelId, documentUrl);

    AnalyzeResult analyzeResult = analyzeDocumentPoller.getFinalResult();

    // pages
    analyzeResult.getPages().forEach(documentPage -> {
      System.out.printf("Page has width: %.2f and height: %.2f, measured with unit: %s%n",
        documentPage.getWidth(),
        documentPage.getHeight(),
        documentPage.getUnit());

      // lines
      documentPage.getLines().forEach(documentLine -> {
        String lineContent = documentLine.getContent();
        System.out.println("Line Content: " + lineContent);
    });

      // words
    documentPage.getWords().forEach(documentWord -> {
        String wordContent = documentWord.getContent();
        double confidence = documentWord.getConfidence();
        System.out.printf("Word: %s, Confidence: %.2f%n", wordContent, confidence);
    });
    });
    }
  }
```

**Output:**

```
Page has width: 1200.00 and height: 900.00, measured with unit: pixel
Line Content: Introductory Paragraph of a Play Review :
Line Content: Recently, I had the pleasure of seeing one of
Line Content: William Shakespeare's most beloved comedies,
Line Content: A Midsummer Night's Dream, performed beautifully
Line Content: at the Los Angeles Repertory Theatre in downtown
Line Content: Los Angeles. At first glance, this performance
Line Content: space looks more like an industrial warehouse than
Line Content: an art house, but walking in you are transformed
Line Content: to the magical land of Midsummer.
Line Content: wikihow
Line Content: wiki How to Write a Paragraph
Word: Introductory, Confidence: 0.98
Word: Paragraph, Confidence: 0.99
Word: of, Confidence: 1.00
Word: a, Confidence: 1.00
Word: Play, Confidence: 0.99
Word: Review, Confidence: 1.00
Word: :, Confidence: 0.95
Word: Recently,, Confidence: 0.99
Word: I, Confidence: 0.96
Word: had, Confidence: 0.99
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[Quickstart: Document Intelligence (formerly Form Recognizer) SDKs - Azure AI services | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/quickstarts/get-started-sdks-rest-api?view=doc-intel-3.1.0&viewFallbackFrom=form-recog-3.0.0&preserve-view=true&pivots=programming-language-java)